# A syntax error occurs in the github repository

Tags: themes, jekyll, github-pages

An error occurs when using Grape-Academic-Theme.

Error message during GitHub repository build process

> Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 17): Unknown tag 'nocite' in /_layouts/hub.html

`layout/hub.html` markup:

```
---
layout: page
---
<div id="hub">
  <section id="header-content">
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="bg"></section>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Aside Navigation  -->
    <aside id="aside" class="col-md-4">
      {% include hubaside.html %}
    </aside>
    <!-- Post List -->
    <section id="content" class="col-md-8">
      {{ page.description | markdownify }}
      <section class="links">
        <h2>Links</h2>
        {% if page.citekey %}
          {% nocite page.citekey %}
          {% bibliography --cited --template pubhublinkstemplate %}
        {% else %}
          <ol class="link-list">
            {% include hubadditionallinks.html %}
          </ol>
        {% endif %}
      </section>
      {{ content }}
      <section class="abs-bibtex">
        {% if page.citekey %}
          {% bibliography --cited --template pubhubabsbibtex %}
        {% endif %}
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

git push .

After that, it doesn't build and doesn't apply to the github page.

Comment: Have you cloned the original repo or a clone? nocite is a custom Jekyll tag and might not be supported in your version.